# Server Agent PowerShell job step - Difference between calling a file and calling a command

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-agent, dbatools

I have some simple PowerShell code to insert a value into a table:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance myserver -Query 'insert into Database.dbo.tbl values (1)'
```

and if I save it as a file, I can call it in a CmdExec job step. However, can anyone tell me why I can't run the command, especially as it is only one line:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver -Query ''insert into DBADatabase.dbo.tbl values (1)'''
```

Can anyone tell me why running as a command will not work, yet the same code as a file can work. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I see something is wrong here `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `

Comment: What is the error and what are you trying to do? This MSDN link will help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Comment: Hi @Hiten004, There is no error! The script runs in ISE, It runs as a file when the server agent job points to it, however if the server agent job is pointed to the command, it runs, completes, but does not insert. The goal is to use commands in the job step as opposed to files on the server. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `powershell.exe ...` command is executed from *outside* PowerShell, possibly via `cmd.exe`.

In that case, *`'...'`-enclosed strings have no syntactical function* and are passed straight through to PowerShell, causing *it* to interpret them as enclosing a *string literal*, which is simply *output as-is* (in other words: your command is *printed* rather than *executed*).

Instead, you must use `"..."` to enclose the command to pass to PowerShell; inside that string, you're free to use `'...'`:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver -Query 'insert into DBADatabase.dbo.tbl values (1)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create test job on my server with below powershell code and it work. Below image have my job detail.

**My Test code**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'MYSERVER' -Query 'insert into DBA_TOOLS.dbo.tbl values (1)'
```

**your code - you are missing single quotes 'myserver' around sql server.**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'myserver' -Query ''insert into DBADatabase.dbo.tbl values (1)'
```

[image]

hope this help

Comment: Thank you @Hiten004 I will test soon and will be very annoyed if its down to something simple like quotes!

Comment: No, there is no need to quote words such as `myserver` used as command arguments in PowerShell, as implied by the OP stating that the command works as part of a script file. The real issue is using single quotes instead of double quotes when passing the command as a command-line argument to `powershell.exe` from _outside_ of PowerShell. Can I suggest you delete your answer?